# How to use grep in a for loop

Tags: bash, unix

Could someone please help with this script. I need to use grep  to loop to through the filenames that need to be changed.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=

for file in  $(ls $1)

do

grep "^.old" |  mv  "$1/$file"  "$1/$file.old"

done
```

Comment: So, if the file does not have a back up (.old) then make back up? Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

`bash` can handle regular expressions without using `grep`.

```
for f in "$1"/*; do
    [[ $f =~ \.old ]] && continue
    # Or a pattern instead
    # [[ $f == *.old* ]] && continue
    mv "$f" "$f.old"
done
```

You can also move the name checking into the pattern itself:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in "$1/"!(*.old*); do
    mv "$f" "$f.old"
done
```

Comment: Why do you need regex here? You could do: `[[ "$f" == *.old ]] && continue`

Comment: True, I didn't make the mental leap from regex to pattern for that step.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make rename a file (i.e. **dir/file.txt** ==> **dir/file.old**) only if the file has not been renamed before. The solution is as follow.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$1/"*
do
    backup_file="${file%.*}.old"
    if [ ! -e "$backup_file" ]
    then
        echo mv "$file" "$backup_file"
    fi
done
```

## Discussion

The script currently does not actual make back up, it only displays the action. Run the script once and examine the output. If this is what you want, then remove the `echo` from the script and run it again.

## Update

Here is the **no if** solution:

```
ls "$1/"* | grep -v ".old" | while read file
do
    echo mv "$file" "${file}.old"
done
```

## Discussion

- The `ls` command displays all files.
- The grep command filter out those files that has the `.old` extension so they won't be displayed.
- The while loop reads the file names that do not have the `.old` extension, one by one and rename them.

Comment: Okay I have 4 file's in my testdir: file1 file2.old file3old file4.old, I want to rename only the files which don't have ".old" extension. But according the assignment I can't use if statement and I need to use grep.

Comment: @user3412751 Please make note of such artificial restrictions in your question.